# How to control the order of zipped directories and files with "archiver.js"?

Tags: node.js, typescript, archiverjs

I am using [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) to zip two folders `x` and `y`:

```
const out = ... // file write stream
...
const zip = archiver('zip', {});
zip.on('error', (err: Error) => { throw err; });

zip.pipe(out);
zip.directory('x', 'x');
zip.directory('y', 'y');
zip.finalize();
```

The zip file is Ok but but `unzip -l` shows `x` and `y` interleaved.
(Looks like the `archiver` traverses `x` and `y` in BFS-order).

```
x/x1
x/x2
y/y1
y/y2
x/x1/x11.txt
x/x2/x21.txt
y/y1/y11.txt
```

I'd like to zip `x` and `y` in DFS-order so `unzip -l` shows:

```
x/x1
x/x1/x11.txt
x/x2
x/x2/x21.txt
y/y1
y/y1/y11.txt
y/y2
```

How can I control the order of zipped directories and files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob()` method instead of `directory()` to match files using a glob pattern.

It will append files in `DFS-order`.

The instruction should look like:

```
zip.glob('{x,y}/**/*');
```

Full code example:

```
import fs = require('fs');
import archiver = require('archiver');

let out = fs.createWriteStream(process.cwd() + '/example.zip');

const zip = archiver('zip', {});
zip.on('error', (err: Error) => { throw err; });

zip.pipe(out);
zip.glob('{x,y}/**/*');
zip.finalize();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the zip unfortunately looks the same :((

Comment: damn it is working as you are expecting on my side with `glob()`

Comment: Hmm ... very weird.

Comment: I tried `zip.glob('x/**/*'); zip.glob('y/**/*');` and it works as expected :)) Thank you !